# Reading and writing file attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the rails console:

```
ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new tempfile: 'tempfilefoo', original_filename: 'filename_foo.jpg', content_type: 'content_type_foo', headers: 'headers_foo'
 => #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000548f3a0 @tempfile="tempfilefoo", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil, @headers=nil>
```

I can write a string to `@tempfile`, and yet `@original_filename`, `@content_type` and `@headers` remain as `nil`

Why is this and how can I write information to these attributes?

And how can I *read* these attributes from a file instance?

i.e.

```
File.new('path/to/file.png')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not documented (and doesn't make much sense), but it looks like [the options `UploadedFile#initialize` takes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e6a8b911906ba0afb76b6c8ce8a916a31c8d3b1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/upload.rb#L25-L32) are `:tempfile`, `:filename`, `:type` and `:head`:

```
def initialize(hash) # :nodoc:
  @tempfile          = hash[:tempfile]
  raise(ArgumentError, ':tempfile is required') unless @tempfile

  @original_filename = encode_filename(hash[:filename])
  @content_type      = hash[:type]
  @headers           = hash[:head]
end
```

Changing your invocation to this ought to work:

```
ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new tempfile: 'tempfilefoo',
  filename: 'filename_foo.jpg', type: 'content_type_foo', head: 'headers_foo'
```

Or you can set them after initialization:

```
file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new tempfile: 'tempfilefoo', filename: 'filename_foo.jpg'
file.content_type = 'content_type_foo'
file.headers = 'headers_foo'
```

I'm not sure I understand your second question, "And how can I *read* these attributes from a file instance?"

You can extract the filename (or last component) from any path with [`File.basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/File.html#method-c-basename):

```
file = File.new('path/to/file.png')
File.basename(file.path) # => "file.png"
```

If you want to get the Content-Type that corresponds to a file extension, you can use Rails' Mime module:

```
type = Mime["png"] # => #<Mime::Type:... @synonyms=[], @symbol=:png, @string="text/png">
type.to_s          # => "text/png"
```

You can put this together with `File.extname`, which gives you the extension:

```
ext = File.extname("path/to/file.png") # => ".png"
ext = ext.sub(/^\./, '') # => "png" (drop the leading dot)
Mime[ext].to_s           # => "text/png"
```

You can see a list of all of the MIME types Rails knows about by typing `Mime::SET` in the Rails console, or [looking at the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89a7187cc0d893da67f53d3215a33043905d68ed/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb), which also shows you how to register other MIME types in case you're expecting other types of files.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, how should I get the headers from a File instance?

Comment: @Starkers A File instance doesn't have "headers." A File instance is just a pointer to a file on your (server's) hard drive. Headers are specific to HTTP, and File has nothing to do with HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

the following should help you:

```
upload = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({ 
    :tempfile => File.new("#{Rails.root}/relative_path/to/tempfilefoo") , #make sure this file exists
    :filename => "filename_foo" # use this instead of original_filename 
})
upload.headers = "headers_foo"
upload.content_type = "content_type_foo"
```

I didn't understand by "And how can I read these attributes from a file instance?", what you exactly want to do.
Perhaps if you want to read the tempfile, you can use:

```
upload.read # -> content of tempfile
upload.rewind # -> rewinds the pointer back so that you can read it again.
```

Hope it helps :) And let me know if I have misunderstood.